# Monitoring what happens inside a VMWare virtual machine

Tags: vmware, monitoring

my question is about a Windows xp computer running one or more xp or Ubuntu virtual machines, via VMWare Player.
What I'm asking is : can I remotely know what happens inside these virtual machines at any time? As I need to monitor what programs get used, written files, visited websites and such.
I forgot to mention that these vms Internet connection is provided through a USB UMTS modem (or in the worst case an iPhone USB tethering, tough it's rare). The host that the VM runs on is instead connected to a LAN, on a windows domain.
Is what I'd like to do possible?
Thanks for any help I will receive

Comment: I am sure you could purchase software to record certain events and send the logs to a desination of your choice.

Comment: Do you have any links? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but can get complicated. If you're willing write your own scripts you can use tools such as [Nagios](http://nagios.org/) or [Veeam Monitor](http://www.veeam.com/vmware-esx-management-one-solution.html) to get the job done.

There is a listing of custom Nagios scripts specifically made for VMware on [Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/*-Virtual-Environments/VMWare).

Comment: Both solutions seem pointed more toward resources performance monitoring rather than resources inspection, am I wrong?

Comment: They're made for monitoring resources. However Nagios can be used to do things such as send you a log report or tell you what processes are currently running. It will be able to do all the things you metnion but you're going to have to roll your own scripts.http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files/check_logfiles/details http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to see if I get more answers before accepting yours that looks like the "winner" at the moment ;)